# How can you get both unique & duplicate values from the array in Python?

Tags: python

I have an array in which I have both unique and duplicated values.

With my current implementation, I'm getting the list of unique & duplicated values, but I want to get also existing unique values (values with no duplication) from the array.

```
array = [2,4,2,4,88,98,88,100,33,100]


def algo(array):
   duplicate = []
   unique = []
   superunique = []

   for item in array:
      if item in unique:
         duplicate.append(item)            
      else:            
         unique.append(item)
   
   print("Duplicate values: ", duplicate)
   print("Unique Values: ", unique)


print(algo(array))
```

My current result is:

> Duplicate values:  [2, 4, 88, 100]
> Unique Values:  [2, 4, 88, 98, 100, 33]

And I want to get also existing unique values that are already in the array

> Existing Unique Values = [98, 33]  ==> desire result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the [set](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/set.html) data structure for this kind of operations.

```
print("Existing unique values :" , set(unique) - set(duplicate))
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach basically takes a hashmap that stores the count of all the array items. From this we can take the super unique list to have all the keys having count exactly 1 and the duplicate list to have all the keys greater than one. All the keys are added into the unique list.

```
array = [2,4,2,4,88,98,88,100,33,100]
countMap = {}

for i in array:
    if countMap.get(i):
        countMap[i]+=1
    else:
        countMap[i]=1

duplicate = []
unique = []
superunique = []
for i in countMap.keys():
    unique.append(i)
    if countMap[i] > 1:
        duplicate.append(i)
    if countMap[i] == 1:
        superunique.append(i)

print("Duplicate values : " , duplicate)  
print("Unique values : " ,unique)
print("Existing unique values :" , superunique)
```

**Output**

```
Duplicate values :  [2, 4, 88, 100]
Unique values :  [2, 4, 88, 98, 100, 33]
Existing unique values : [98, 33]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Counter` from collections library. [The documentation is over here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html)

```py
from collections import Counter;
array = [2,4,2,4,88,98,88,100,33,100]
counts = Counter(array) # Counter({2: 2, 4: 2, 88: 2, 100: 2, 98: 1, 33: 1})
counts_in_dict = dict(counts) # {2: 2, 4: 2, 88: 2, 98: 1, 100: 2, 33: 1}

dv = [] # Duplicate Values
uv = [] # Unique Values

for key,value in counts_in_dict.items():
   if (value == 1 ):
       uv.append( key ) 
   else:
       dv.append( key )

print(uv)
print(dv)

# Unique Values
# [98, 100]
# Duplicate Values
# [2, 4, 88, 100]
```

[image: The code in action]

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter
array = [2,4,2,4,88,98,88,100,33,100]
counter_ele = Counter(array)
duplicate = []
ext_unique = []
print(counter_ele)
for key,value in counter_ele.items():
    if value >1:
        duplicate.append(key)
    else:
        ext_unique.append(key)
print('duplicate ->', duplicate)
print('existing unique ->', ext_unique)
print('unique ->', list(counter_ele.keys()))
```

**Output**

```
Counter({2: 2, 4: 2, 88: 2, 100: 2, 98: 1, 33: 1})
duplicate -> [2, 4, 88, 100]
existing unique -> [98, 33]
unique -> [2, 4, 88, 98, 100, 33]
```

Answer (score 1):

As many have shown the Counter class is the way to go. You can compress the rest of the code shown to a single list comprehension or `set` call:

```
elements = [2,4,2,4,88,98,88,100,33,100]

# are unique
>>> [val for val, count in Counter(elements).items() if count == 1]
[98, 33]

# have duplicates
>>> [val for val, count in Counter(elements).items() if count > 1]
[2, 4, 88, 100]

# unique values
>>> set(elements)
{33, 2, 98, 100, 4, 88}
```

And when you have either those that are unique or those that are duplicates, you can subtract that set from the set of all values to find the other set:

```
>>> duplicates = [val for val, count in Counter(elements).items() if count > 1]
>>> set(elements) - set(duplicates)
{33, 98}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Collections Counter. Try this code:

```
import collections
array = [2,4,2,4,88,98,88,100,33,100]
 
def algo(array):
    duplicate = [element for element, count in collections.Counter(array).items() if count > 1]
    unique = [element for element, count in collections.Counter(array).items() if count == 1]
    print("Duplicate values: ", duplicate)
    print("Unique Values: ", unique)

print(algo(array))
```

Answer (score 1):

watch this to get all value in list even Super Unique

```
arrays = [2, 4, 2, 4, 88, 98, 88, 100, 33, 100]


def algo(n):

    duplicate = []
    unique = []
    superunique = []

    for item in arrays:
        if item in unique:
            duplicate.append(item)
        else:
            unique.append(item)

        superunique = set(unique) - set(duplicate)



    print("Duplicate values: ", duplicate)
    print("Unique Values: ", unique)
    print("Super Unique Value :", superunique)
```